# JavaScript to C# data structure

Tags: javascript, c#

i am working on converting a Javascript code into C# to use it as ASP application,

i wonder equivalent data structure for the following javascript in C#

```
var ports = {
'critical': [21,3389,4444,3444],
'medium': [25],
'safe': [80,443]
};
```

Comment: object with 3 arrays

Comment: What does php have to do with it?

Comment: well, this data structure classify the severity of ports to print them in table with different color according to its severity

Comment: why not use just something like: struct Ports { int[] critical; int[] medium ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a C# dictionary. Here's my implementation of it:

```
Dictionary<string, int[]> dict = new Dictionary<string, int[]>()
        {
            {"critical", new int[] {21,3389,4444,3444} },
            {"medium", new int[] {25} },
            {"safe", new int[] {80,443} },
        };

        foreach( KeyValuePair<string, int[]> kvp in dict )
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Key = {0}, Value = {1}", kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
        }
```

**EDIT:**
Try using the following to find the key.

```
string key = dict.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value.Contains(25)).Key;
Console.WriteLine(key);
```

Comment: Great Jony, one more clarification, could you please edit the answer to show me how to get critical, medium or safe by passing 25 as value to dict ?